# Inheritance of UIView for adding new logic or extend UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I make an app and in it, I need to create `UITextView` with a placeholder. I have made this by inheritance and made my own UITextView class as a delegate by them self (put some logic on begin editing and end editing).

A look for information about: `Is it correct to put such logic into UIView?`, and found a lot of articles that said that you should not do this, but do not find why?

I try to find information about is it correct to inherit UIView classes and given them some new logic (for example: choosing colors, fonts, make as delegates, calculating layout dimensions and ...) or try to use ViewControllers or custom presenterControllers

In what cases you should use inheritance, and why? At what you should not? What are the best practices and why they are the best?

example:

```
class PlaceholderTextView: UITextView {

    override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupViews()
    }

    private func setupViews() {
        self.delegate = self
        self.text = "Enter some text..."
        self.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        self.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
    }
}

extension PlaceholderTextView: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if self.textColor == UIColor.lightGray {
            self.text = nil
            self.textColor = UIColor.black
            self.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
        }
    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if self.text.isEmpty {
            self.text = "Enter some text..."
            self.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
            self.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post your logic brah

Comment: @DevilDecoder     add

Answer (score 0):

**In which case you should inherit**

when you want to add something additional to existing class like you have done with the `UITextView` class placeholder is not provided by the `textview` although it has property `placeholder`

secondly for the code reusability. for example, in `UITextField` class, you want to change the placeholder rect for all the text field in the project then you are not going to change property for placeholder rect in each view controller instead you make one sub class of `UItextField` and use that class

**Is it correct to put such logic into UIView?**

in case you want to do some custom drawing than you have to override the `Draw()` method of `UIView` for that you have to put logic in `UIView` subclass